# How to compute bias-variance components of linear models using R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to understand the how to compute the components Variance and Bias of the total Error (e.g. http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html).

Assume that I have available a dataset of 1000 observations. Firstly, I split the dataset into (90-10) training and testing set and I compute the total training and test error as below:

```
lm1 = lm (Y ~ X1, data = data[1:900,])
lm2 = lm (Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data[1:900,])

train_error1 = sqrt(mean(residuals(lm1)^2))
train_error2 = sqrt(mean(residuals(lm2)^2))

pred_error1 = mean((predict(lm1, data = data[901:1000,]) - data[901:1000,]$Y)^2)
pred_error2 = mean((predict(lm2, data = data[901:1000,]) - data[901:1000,]$Y)^2)
```

In order to estimate the Variance and Bias components of the above models do I need to split the initial dataset of 1000 observations into K smaller sets and then for each of these smaller set do the above computation? If yes, what is the formula for computing these two components?